# Application with ID has not been granted the capability to use the property message

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, sharing

I am trying to post custom fb objects on my wall using php facebook sdk and facebook graph api. And i am getting this error. I tried, but could not find specific answer about that. Even is not mentioned on Facebook Itself. Is there anyone can help me to get this issue resolve.

Comment: it would be better if newbies like me on stackoverflow could get the reason of down rating. So that guys like me should be aware for the future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about publishing an Open Graph action, I suppose?

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#create:

> Optional Parameters Requiring Review
>
> You must request these optional properties during the [Open Graph submission flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/).

The `message` parameter is one of those that need to be approved by Facebook before you can use them.

Comment: It works! I found the problem. Thank you to drive me in correct direction.