# Facebook mention tagging users outside of your app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, tagging

Facebook recently allowed mention tagging in the Open Graph
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/

I'm working on developing an application to share photos and I want my users to be able to tag other Facebook users via mention tagging even if these Facebook users are not currently using my app.

From their API, it appears to be possible, however, I haven't been able to test it out because it requires a Facebook approved action for tagging.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't been able to test it out because it requires a Facebook approved action for tagging.

Actions do not have to be approved for them to be tested with [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

So just create two of those from your app settings panel, make them become friends … and go ahead with testing your mention tagging.

Comment: this works for regular tagging. However, to use mention tagging I need to be able to attach a message to the request. I get back  
  
`{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Application with ID 276337352481582 has not been granted the capability to use the property message.","code":1611165}}`  
  
Looking this up further seems to suggest it's the same permissions I need to get approved by Facebook:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033924/application-with-id-has-not-been-granted-the-capability-to-use-the-property-mess)